# Normalizing redux-form values set with initialValues

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

When I set my formvalues using initialValues, I want the normalization and async validation to run. I even tried dispatching both the blur and change action, but both don't work:

`dispatch(blur('userdata', 'user_zipcode', '3021LC'));`

`dispatch(change('userdata', 'user_zipcode', '3021LC'));`

What would be the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

As for normalizing, it's a little strange that you are initializing with non-normalized data. I would recommend reviewing the [Value Lifecycle](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/) and perhaps using a combination of a `parse` and `format` functions.

As for running async validation, again it's odd that you might be initializing with invalid data, but there is a [`this.props.asyncValidate()` function](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/Props.md/#-asyncvalidate-function-) that you can call in your form component to trigger the async validation.

Does that help?

Comment: That did help :). The "problem" here, is that this form is pre-filled with userdata. I just want to double-check (and normalize) the data. I found a way to normalize the data here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1988#issuecomment-264558513. However, the async validation doesn't work... If I'm correct, I should just be able to run this.props.asyncValidate() in my decorated form, after dispatching the initialize-action, right?

Comment: It doesn't run the asyncValidator-function at all... Anything you can think of that I could have missed?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having this same problem while using initialValues and not getting them normalized:

Using `format` instead of `normalize` seems to fix the problem but
`format` doesn't actually change the data you have on your store like the `normalize` does so, if you want to do that, then using both may be the best way to fix this? I'm not sure...

So, here's an example:

`<Field component={MyCustomInputField} name="phone" format={normalizePhone} normalize={normalizePhone} label="Phone" type="tel" />`

`format` is the first thing on the [Value Lifecycle Hooks](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/)

Hope this helps!